# Nginx reverse proxy destination from request url

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm having problem configuring Nginx to have:

- a reverse proxy with the destination server from the request url
- the port could be the default (80) but if also this can be from the request url it's great
- the behaviour I'd like to be calling http://nginxserver/destinationserver then

nginx will call destinationserver (taken from the request url and not fixed in the location)

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work

```
location  ~^\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) {
proxy_pass http://$1:$2/$3;
}
```

I need the above behaviour because we have a static VPN from one server, where I could have nginx, and some other remote devices. Each of these device has a webserver that show from the default port 80 the device status. The problem is that only from within the server (that has the VPN), we can reach each remote device, so I'm trying with Nginx to enable a reverse proxy to reach the devices from outside of the server.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

This is the solution I've found:

```
location  ~ "/go/([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})(.+)$" {
    proxy_pass http://$1:80$2;  
    sub_filter "<head>" "<head><base href=\"${scheme}://${host}/go/$1/\">";     
    sub_filter_once off;    
    sub_filter_types application/json application/x-javascript;     
    sub_filter '"/flash/' '"/go/$1/flash/';     
    sub_filter '"/rom/' '"/go/$1/rom/'; 
}
```

For example I can use the following url: http://myproxyserver/go/192.168.0.100/
and I get the response from the 192.168.0.100 throw the nginx reverse proxy.